# Div created using JQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have a strange problem with JQuery, I am trying to use a text field which uses autocomplete of JQuery UI to show suggestions, and appends each selected text value to a div. Along with each text label, there is a remove link as well, but I cannot get it to work.

The autocomplete works like a charm:

```
 $( "#games" ).autocomplete({
                source: "<?php echo base_url('game/game/autocomplete'); ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                minLength: 1, // how many character when typing to display auto complete
                // handling the select
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                  $('#showgames').append('<span id="'+ui.item.value+'">'+ui.item.value+'<a href=# class="removegame">Remove</span>');
                    $('#games').val('');
                    return false;
                }
            });
            // removing game items
            $('.removegame').click(function(){
                // The following never happens
                    alert("hi");
                });

  <div id="showgames">
       // anchor links are generated by jquery here, within individual spans.
       // these are not working
            </div>

            <div id="testing">
                // This works
                <a class=removegame href=#>Test link</a></span> 
            </div>
```

Auto complete field: ( Games )

```
            <td align="left"><label for="genres">Genre(s):</label></td>
```

The showgames div has each span corresponding to each value obtained from the "games" text field. Here, clicking on a link with remove game does nothing. It should actually enter the function as above, and display an alert, but it never happens.

On the contrary, if I create an anchor tag item on the page with the class removegame, it works. But when it was generated using jQuery, it doesn't work. I am driven nuts. Can someone please help me?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use `.on` this way

```
$("#showgames").on('click','.removegame',function(){
        // The will happen now
        alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your links are dynamically created, they're not around when the removal function is being appended to the links. Instead, it's better to write your code to check for the removegame class on an element when a click event takes place:

```
$("#showgames").on('click', '.removegame', function(){
    // Your code here
    console.log("hello");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Within your select function you need to hook up the event on the newly added link. Basically, you can move this code:

```
    // removing game items
    $('.removegame').click(function(){
        // The following never happens
            alert("hi");
        });
```

inside of your select function.

Comment: This would work for a single link, but invoking it every time a link is added would mean iterating back through all of the `.removegame` elements on the page again instead of just thew newly added link.